# How does app.cookieSession() middleware differentiate between users?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

**Question:** How does connect uniquely identify each user with which there is an active sesson? (How does it populate the req.session variable with the correct information)?

I looked into the source code and I'm not sure where this happens.

As I understand it, connect sets a real cookie on the client's computer representing some encoding that is then used to uniquely identify the user. The actual 'cookies' are stored on the server-side.

I'm not really sure where the storage and retrieval is happening at all.

See: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html

For example: the second console.log represents the actual cookies. The long string there is the 'key' used to map the user to the proper cookies on the server. The first console.log is that user's cookies stored on the server.

```
//console.log(req.session)
{ loggedIn: true, //set using req.session.loggedIn
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }

//console.log(req.cookies);
{ name: 'tobi', //Set using res.cookies()
  { connect.sess: 's:j:{}.RyNbcl0K94AFiRT63nqw3bH/thtzbWbDQRwtP45pmAE'}
```

Comment: You do not understand it correctly. :-) The secret isn't encoded and set as a cookie. The secret encodes the cookie (well, is encoded with the cookie would be more accurate) which is set on the browser. The purpose is to prevent cookie forgery/spoofing. The source code is [right in the doc](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html) for connect.